# Python Anaconda ImportError No module named menuinst.knownfolders

Tags: python, anaconda

I am just starting to learn Python. Having used R Studio and Matlab, I was looking for a similar IDE.

I downloaded Python 2.7 and then downloaded Anaconda IDE. However, when I try to open Python using either Spyder/iPython/ Jupyter NB under the Anaconda folder, a command window flashes open and then closes. Below is the error I captured from the cmd window:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\cwp.py", line 9, in <module>
      from menuinst.knownfolders import FOLDERID, get_folder_path, PathNotFoundException
  ImportError: No module named menuinst.knownfolders
```

I am using Windows10 64bit. 
Could someone kindly help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following command in the cmd:

```
conda install menuinst
```

This should install the menuinst package, as you appear to not have it installed.