# Python Anaconda ImportError: menuinst.knownfolders

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, conda

I am trying to work with my Jupyter notebook. I have done so for the last 6 six years or so. Now I am getting the following error message:

Python Anaconda ImportError No module named menuinst.knownfolders
I checked several posts on the internet but nothing has helped: “conda install menuinst”. see here:

[Python Anaconda ImportError No module named menuinst.knownfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126438/python-anaconda-importerror-no-module-named-menuinst-knownfolders)

I now have uninstalled and re-installed it three times but did not solve the issue.
When I go to my anaconda prompt and type in “jupyter notebook”, these are the error message I am getting:

```
C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
  warnings.warn(
_cffi_ext.c
AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c(268): fatal error C1083: 
Cannot open include file: 'zmq.h': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 49, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

Just another piece of information, my anaconda prompt starts with (base) before it says C:\user\user>. Is that relevant or this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
conda remove zeromq
conda install zeromq
```

Comment: thanks for your response.
When I do those two commands I am getting quite a bit of error messages. Most of them look tlike this:

  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 64, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    import _win32sysloader
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _win32sysloader: %1 is not a valid Win32 applicatiodone

Comment: Hi, I tried the above and now I am getting the following error message: 
"A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration."

Can you help me further, please?

Comment: you try pip install --upgrade tornado==5.1.1

Answer (score 0):

**Solution-1**

Please try to reinstall jupyter notebook from anaconda navigator it will definitely work

**Solution-2**

Please update jupyter notebook from anaconda prompt with below commands.

```
pip install notebook --upgrade
conda update notebook
```

Comment: Dear @Munawar,
Thanks for your response. I tried solution 2 but that is not working.
Then I tried solution 1 but my ananconda is not starting up when I click on it.
Any suggestions as to why this is the case?
Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335789/anaconda-navigator-wont-launch-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue..

1)Open anaconda prompt and type

```
conda list
```

2)Check terminado and

```
terminado 0.8.3
zeromq    4.3.2
```

3)In same anaconda prompt and check if python is working, type below code

```
 python
```

4. if yes then

   quit()

5)if no update python accordingly.

6)Type,

```
anaconda-navigator
```

7. This will open navigator and try to install jupyter notebook.